# Prevent circle of going out of the canvas/window if circle is bigger than canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

How can I prevent the circle so it never goes out of the canvas/window in case the circle is bigger than the canvas?

I need it to auto-adjust to the maximum available size. What would be the best solution to fix this? I know using drag function can fix this issue but I need to get this done with 2 clicks. The first click would define the center point and the second click the radius.

WPF xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="ShapeAnimator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShapeAnimator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Step" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Canvas Name="Canvas1" 
                Background="#000000"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="376" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792"
                MouseDown="Canvas1_MouseDown"
                
                />
        <Label 
            Name="CoordLabel"
            Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="708,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.362,0.083"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ShapeAnimator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int ClickStep = 1;
        double x1, y1;

        List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
        private Animator animator;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            animator = new Animator((int)Canvas1.Width, (int)Canvas1.Height);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Circle c in circles)
            {
                animator.Animate(c);
            }

            RefreshScreen();
        }


        private void Canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            double x = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas1).X;
            double y = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas1).Y;
            CoordLabel.Content = x.ToString() + ":" + y.ToString();
            
            if (ClickStep > 0)
            {
                x1 = x;
                y1 = y;
                DrawCircle(x1, y1, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                double radius = Math.Sqrt((x - x1) * (x - x1) + (y - y1) * (y - y1));

                Circle c = new Circle(x1, y1, radius);
                circles.Add(c);

                RefreshScreen();
            }

            ClickStep = -ClickStep;
        }


        private void RefreshScreen()
        {
            ClearScreen();
            foreach(Circle c in circles)
            {
                DrawCircle(c.x, c.y, c.radius);
            }
        }

        private void ClearScreen()
        {
            Canvas1.Children.Clear();
        }

        private void DrawCircle(double x, double y, double radius)
        {
            Ellipse c = new Ellipse()
            {
                Width = radius * 2,
                Height = radius * 2,
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1
            };

            Canvas1.Children.Add(c);
            c.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - radius);
            c.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - radius);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: will setting ClipToBounds property of the canvas work ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why drag would fix it but surely the moment that the first click is done you can know its location and hence the shortest distance to all the 4 edges of the canvas and hence you can work out the maximum possible radius. Either at the time of the first click or the time of the second, do that calc, do the radius calc, if the radius is larger than the max, reduce the radius. For example:

```
        else
        {
            double radius = Math.Sqrt((x - x1) * (x - x1) + (y - y1) * (y - y1));

            if(radius > x1)
              radius = x1;
            if(radius > y1)
              radius = y1;
            if(radius > Canvas1.Width - x1)
              radius = Canvas1.Width - x1;
            if(radius > Canvas1.Height - y1)
              radius = Canvas1.Height - y1;
```

The radius will end up at the smallest distance to an edge after these 4 if statements

ps; do please name your controls something more apt than Canvas1, Textbox1 etc- programs get very hard to follow when they have huge number of controls all called TypenameN